# Compute the PDF, CDF and expected value of variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, exponential-distribution

I'm working with this question, but I'm not sure about my answer, can you help me check it?

The question:
[image]
My answer:
[image]
Thank for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Correct.
2. and 3. Incorrect.

Density function for 2. (using convolution) is $f_V(v)=\alpha\beta\int\limits_0^ve^{-\beta x}e^{-\alpha(v-x)}dx=\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha-\beta}(e^{-\beta v}-e^{-\alpha v})$.

Density function for 3.   $F_W(w)=P(W\le w)=P(X^2\le w)=P(X\le\sqrt{w})$$=1-e^{-\alpha \sqrt{w}}$,  giving $f_W(w)=\frac{\alpha}{2\sqrt{w}}e^{-\alpha \sqrt{w}}$.

I presume you can compute expectations.